# python: xml.etree.ElementTree, removing "namespaces"

Tags: python, xml

I like the way ElementTree parses xml, in particular the Xpath feature. I've an output in xml from an application with nested tags.

I'd like to access this tags by name without specifying the namespace, is it possible?
For example:

```
root.findall("/molpro/job")
```

instead of:

```
root.findall("{http://www.molpro.net/schema/molpro2006}molpro/{http://www.molpro.net/schema/molpro2006}job")
```

Comment: I want to add a note, In my example the namespace is the same, but in the whole Xml file there are other, variable namespaces. I want just to turn off this feature, like in the xml.dom.minidom parser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At least with lxml2, it's possible to reduce this overhead somewhat:

```
root.findall("/n:molpro/n:job",
             namespaces=dict(n="http://www.molpro.net/schema/molpro2006"))
```

Answer (score 5):

You could write your own function to wrap the nasty looking bits for example:

```
def my_xpath(doc, ns, xp);
    num = xp.count('/')
    new_xp = xp.replace('/', '/{%s}')
    ns_tup = (ns,) * num
    doc.findall(new_xp % ns_tup)

namespace = 'http://www.molpro.net/schema/molpro2006'
my_xpath(root, namespace, '/molpro/job')
```

Not that much fun I admit but a least you will be able to read your xpath expressions.