# namespaces complication when using ElementTree or cElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, celementtree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python: xml.etree.ElementTree, removing “namespaces”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703882/python-xml-etree-elementtree-removing-namespaces)

I have a sample xml document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<school xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.school.org">
<name>John</name>
<name>Ferus</name>
<name>Greg</name>
</school>
```

And I have the below python code to find names,

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree

with open('sample.xml', 'rt') as f:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)
root = tree.getroot()
for name in root.findall("{http://www.school.org}name"):
    print name.text
```

Providing the namespace each time I search for a tag is clumsy. Is there a better way?

Comment: @MartijnPieters i'm looking for a solution using ElementTree and not lxml2

Comment: Perhaps, but unfortunately that still makes your question a duplicate of the other question. You can place a bounty on that question asking for a non-LXML option too if needed.