# using html5lib with xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xhtml, elementtree, html5lib

I need is a way to use the html5lib parser to generate a real xml.etree.ElementTree. (lxml is not an option for portability reasons.)

`ELementTree.parse` [can take a parser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.parse) as an optional parameter

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(source, parser=None)
```

but it's not clear what such a parser would look like. Is there a class or object within HTML5 I could use for the `parser` argument? Documentation for both libraries on this issue is thin.

---

**Context**:

I have a malformed XHTML file that can't be parsed with `ElementTree.parse`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Title</title></head>
<body><div class="cls">Note that this br<br>is missing a closing slash</div></body>
</html>
```

So I used `html5lib.parse` instead with the default `treebuilder="etree"` parameter, which worked fine.

But html5lib apparently does not output an `xml.etree.ElementTree` object, just one with a near-identical API. There are two problems with this:

- html5lib's `find` does not support the [`namespaces` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14853417/1180926), making XPath excessively verbose without a clumsy [wrapper function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1704596/1180926).
- The Eclipse debugger does not support drill-through of html5lib etrees.

So I cannot use either ElementTree or html5lib alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given `xml.etree.ElementTree` as `etree` (as it is commonly imported as):

What's returned is not an `etree.ElementTree`, but rather an `etree.Element` (this is the same as what `etree.fromstring` returns; only `etree.parse` returns an `etree.ElementTree`). It is genuinely part of the etree module — it's not something with a similar API. The problem you've run into applies to `etree.fromstring` as much as it does html5lib.

The Python [documentation for `xml.etree.ElementTree`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) doesn't mention the `namespaces` argument — it seems to be an undocumented feature of `ElementTree` objects (but not `Element` objects). As such, it's probably not something that should really be relied on! Your best bet is likely going to be to use a wrapper function.

The fact that Eclipse cannot go through the trees is down to the fact that html5lib defaults to `xml.etree.cElementTree` when it exists — which is meant to be identical, per the module's documentation, but is implemented in C using CPython's API, stopping Eclipse's debugger from functioning. You can get a treebuilder using the non-accelerated version (note from Python 3.3 *both* are the C implementation — `cElementTree` merely survives as a deprecated alias) using the below:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
import html5lib

tb = html5lib.getTreeBuilder("etree", implementation=etree)
p = html5lib.HTMLParser(tb)
tree = p.parse("<html>")
```

Comment: @Arithmomaniac Thanks for saying — edited it to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the response in an `ElementTree`

```
>>> from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
>>> from html5lib import parse
>>>
>>> ElementTree(parse("<html>"))
<xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree at 0x...>
```